# Connect an Ipad to a controller

Tags: ipad, wifi, rs485

I need to run an application in my ipad which has to talk wirelessly to a controller. The controller communicates on serial as well as RS485 port. It doesn't have a wifi adapter.
What are the options for me to do this ?

One thought is, I have to buy a wifi to RS485 adapter which I will attach to my controller and then my ipad can connect to the controller through the wifi adapter. Is this feasible? My doubts are because, I am not sure whether Ipad has the capability to open a raw socket connection to the remote wifi adapter (on the controller).

If not, then what are the other options which are available for me ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with fairly straight forward electronics and programming, this is how I would do it.

I would forget about having them talk directly and instead use the internet, you can get cheap  controller called an Electric Imp that you can create code for using their online portal to connect your device to the internet, the device itself connects up using wifi and its own secure VPN.

Once you have it connected up you can create you own webpage or app to talk to their cloud, this has the added advantage you can now control your device wherever you can get an internet connection and your device can continue to interact to the internet even when your ipad is off.

http://electricimp.com

Comment: Any information regarding on how to create an app to talk to their cloud? (I was planning to make the app with Android SDK and BlinkUp library, but not sure how)

Comment: They have examples on their website, I created a demo fairly quickly for a talk I was giving using their examples. For the front end I just used static HTML (and jquery to handle the ajax)

Comment: Apologies for my lack of knowledge. I have no experience in making apps, but I have been learning Android SDK for the past couple of days. Are you saying I should look into jQuery and Ajax in order to control the imp? Would you mind providing a link of one of the examples that you find useful for beginners?

Comment: No, not really, I was just making the point you could use something as simple as HTML to knock together an app, which would also carry the advantage of being multi-platform, in my case, no matter what device the audience had, going to the URL (I printed out a QR code) gave them control of the demo device